# Div with forced max width when possible

Tags: css

I want to create a `div` that has a `max-width`. But also I want that, whenever possible, `max-width` is achieved.

One could say that this is achievable by using `min-width`. The problem is that I also want the `div` to automatically shrink, when needed.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried `width: 100%;` along with the `max-width` definition?

Comment: Yes, the problem with that is that I also don't want the div to be at full parent width, but a specific max-width

Comment: @Greg you meant using both?

Comment: Yes, see here https://jsfiddle.net/7a81a751/

Comment: @Greg Ah yes, it works exactly like I wanted, very simple. Post it like an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `Flexbox`, all you need to set is [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) or `flex: 0 1 300px`, so now element will grow to maximum of `300px` but it will also shrink if needed as you can see here when you resize window [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/254/)

```css
.content {
  display: flex; 
}

.box {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box:last-child {
  flex-basis: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```